# Is there any similarity between 'yield' and 'return' statement in python?Also is it possible to create object of a function?

Tags: python

```
**def colour_generator(lst):
    for i in lst:
        yield i
 print()
 colours=['red','green','blue']
 print(colour_generator(colours))**
```

here the funtion colour_generetor returns the object address
but if in the same code we replace 'yield' with 'return' then it 
returns the first element in the list(lst)..
**Is 'yield' completely different from 'return' statement ?**

Moreover **is it really possible to create object of a function?**As the output when 'return' statement is used instead of 'yield' statement in the above code is :"" or it is something else ?

Comment: Your description of observed behaviour shows that they are in fact different - the former returning a generator, the latter a value.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of observed behaviour shows that they are in fact different - the former returning a generator, the latter a value.

> is it really possible to create object of a function?

A function *is* an object of type/class `function`:

```
# Python 2
>>> f = lambda x: x
>>> type(f)
<type 'function'>

>>> def g(): pass
>>> type(g)
<type 'function'>

# Python 3
>>> f = lambda x: x
>>> type(f)
<class 'function'>
```